# How to get response by clicking button

Tags: android

In these code i am using volley library to use request and response.and URL of json holder to get response.I am getting "title" as my response.but i want this response after clicking a button but i don't how to attach this url to the button to get response title.i tried this till now.

```
package com.example.volleydemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button Click;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Click = findViewById(R.id.Click);
        Click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RequestQueue requestQueue;
                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                        null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("myapp", "the response is" + response.getString("title"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong");
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

            }
        });
    }
}


 
05/12 17:01:44: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 49 s 433 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.volleydemo/com.example.volleydemo.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3548 on device 'Pixel_2_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/mple.volleydem: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mple.volleydem: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

after using sandesh khutalsaheb first option application is crashing can't see the button when i am opening app it suddenly crashes

```
beginning of crash
    

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.volleydemo, PID: 3548
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.volleydemo/com.example.volleydemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
            at com.example.volleydemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3548 SIG: 9
```

adding XML for above code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Click"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

now getting the response perfectly can show this response title on screen too after clicking the button.

```
05/12 17:31:08: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 52 s 574 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.volleydemo/com.example.volleydemo.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3965 on device 'Pixel_2_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/mple.volleydem: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mple.volleydem: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf5d16c80, tid 3995
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf5d16ba0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf5d16ba0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf60733f0) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf5d0e860, tid 3995
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f7ffe000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/Volley: [321] NetworkUtility.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 0x234d8c1 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3108], [size=83], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
D/myapp: the response isdelectus aut autem
```

Comment: Your onClick handler is empty. Move the code after the `Log.d` into the onClick handler.

Comment: `ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`

Comment: ok so what should i edit can you please explain in answer

Comment: you will add XML I will update code from my end as per you changes

Comment: i have added the XML

Comment: @shiga123 now try any code I have changed your button ID use any option both will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        Button Click;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Click = findViewById(R.id.button);
            Click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
      RequestQueue requestQueue;
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                    null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("myapp", "the response is" + response.getString("title"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong");
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
         }

        });
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2--**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        Button Click;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Click = findViewById(R.id.button);
            Click.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
 int id = view.getId();
            // Show different message when click different view component.
            if(id == R.id.button)
{
            RequestQueue requestQueue;
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                    null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("myapp", "the response is" + response.getString("title"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong");
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
        }
    }
```

**OPTION 3-- Changes like show data in UI**

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Click"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/Textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Class File--

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button Click;
    AppCompatTextView showData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Click.setOnClickListener(this);
        showData = findViewById(R.id.Textview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.button) {
            RequestQueue requestQueue;
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n") JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                    null, response -> {
                try {
                    showData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.d(TAG, "the response is" + response.getString("title"));
                    showData.setText(" ID" + response.getString("id") + "\n Title-" +
                            response.getString("title") + "\n Completed-" +
                            response.getString("completed") + "\n User ID"
                            + response.getString("userId") + "\n");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, error -> Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong"));
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error in requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  error is Required type:
Context
Provided:
OnClickListener using first one trying 2nd

Comment: Try this         requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

Comment: check changes with Option 2

Comment: please check latest edit i used first option application is crashing while i am trying to open it .i have added logs

Comment: @shiga123 can you share your xml Because "Click" id is assigned to your Button or  ConstraintLayout please confirm.

Comment: @shiga123 now try any code I have changed your button ID use any option both will work for you

Comment: hi sandesh see the new edit.it is working fine but can we show the response on screen too after clicking the button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244687/discussion-between-shiga123-and-sandesh-khutalsaheb).